# Where is PHPExcel.php file located

Tags: php, export, phpexcel, phalcon

I want to create an excel file in my phalcon php app. I've downloaded PHPExcel, but I am not able to find where the PHPExcel.php file is located. Could anyone tell me where it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the library folder (PHPExcel/Classes/) phalcon_project/app/library/.
To use the class, you must use the method of registerDirs \Phalcon\Loader
See more in [create Excel file in Phalcon php framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303339/create-excel-file-in-phalcon-php-framework)

Answer (score 0):

In the [downloaded zip file](http://download-codeplex.sec.s-msft.com/Download/Release?ProjectName=phpexcel&DownloadId=688490&FileTime=130146594346670000&Build=20798) `PHPExcel_1.7.9_doc.zip`, there is a folder called `Classes`, there you can find `PHPExcel.php`. You only need to insert the whole `Classes` folder and include `PHPExcel.php` for a correct implementation.